# Importing Anaconda libraries not working

Tags: 16.04, bash, python

I have installed tensorflow in Jupyter notebook using the `conda install tensorflow` command. I wanted to import tensorflow in the Ubuntu bash shell, but I couldn't do it.

In fact, it was not possible to import any Anaconda libraries as well.

This is the script:

```
sriswaroop@9DK4BS1:~$ python3
Python 3.6.9 (default, Jul 17 2020, 12:50:27)
[GCC 8.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow as tf
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'
```

Now the funny thing is that when I import a library that came with python, like json or random, it actually runs. So I think there is something up with Anaconda. Thanks!!

Comment: Doesn't look like you're using Anaconda from that output (you should see `Anaconda, Inc. on linux`). What do you get with just `python`? Does `conda env list` show any environment activated -- if not, run `conda activate <env name>`.

Answer (score 0):

The python environment that you are using in the screenshot is not the anaconda environment.

Try running `python` instead of `python3`. If not, maybe the conda path is not sourced. Try the steps below:

1. Check if the anaconda path is available in your PATH by `echo $PATH`
2. If it's not, run the below scripts

```sh
 source <path to anaconda>/bin/activate
 conda init
```

The default anaconda installation path is: `/home/<your-username>/anaconda3`

Checkout the [Anaconda FAQs](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/faq/#distribution-faq-linux-path) for more information. If you have any further issues, please post the details here